# Validity of the Iranian Visa, Multiple entry and Stay periods

Tags: visas, iran, visa-expiration

I've been confused about a multiple entry (twice) visa offering a 90-day stay for each entry but having a validity of 90 days only.

There's no way that one can stay for up to 180 days since validity is restricted. (90 days only)

Let's say upon first entry, assuming on 03/03 (3rd March), I have to enter the same day as visa issuance, and then exit and re-enter the day before the expiry on 05/31 (31st May) in order to stay maximum number of days.

In other words, I want to know how to best utilize validity for a stay as long as you can.

I feel like I wasted money on this multiple entry. I would have been better off with two single entry visas applied at different times.

[image]

Comment: It would make sense if the last *entry* date is 31 May 2022 with a maximum stay of 90 days.

Comment: seems like double entry visa is meant to be for consecutive entries, if there's a gap between two entries, one should apply for separate single entry visas.

Comment: my complain was if I paid extra for double entry, why restricted me within a box of 90 days, I should have been given a 180 day validity at least.

Comment: You have misunderstood me. I am suggesting that it would make sense if 31 May 2022 is the last arrival date, not the last departure date, and you should find out if you are allowed to stay 90 days if you arrive on 31 May. The immigration officer decides when you must leave, on the day that you arrive.

Comment: What travel dates did you include in your visa application?

Comment: @WeatherVane so exactly... you are trying to squeeze 2 entries within 90 day validity, its only good for consecutive entries between exits for maximum utilization of stays. This 90 day validity is the bottleneck actually and doesn't make sense for a dual entry visa, they should have given more validity, that was my complaint.

Comment: @Traveller worst, they didn't ask for it, their system assumes I'm traveling the same day as the application, not evening accounting for a possibility of a travel date in future. I remember other countries I apply for, they do ask for travel dates.

Comment: @AppDeveloper so what is your question, please? I have madde a suggestion – that you ask the visa issuer what the validity is – but you keep repeating the complaint.

Comment: I guess it boils down to, is it a norm for a double entry visa to have a validity of only 90 days? So I can prevent this from happening in future.

Comment: You don't even say which country the visa is for: that country's website should explain all the visa terms and conditions.

Comment: it is for Iran, and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: ...nor the type of visa, nor where you are from. The website for [Iran](https://evisatraveller.mfa.ir/en/request/visa_types/) states: *"Should you need more information, please contact an Iranian consulate in your country"*.

Comment: Because most travelers don't stay for 90 days? So they're expecting two shorter trips within the 90 day period.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was another issue, reaching out to them, all looked good on paper except when you actually try to reach them.

Comment: @mkennedy that's helpful, in other words, i should apply for two separate visas if I want to utilize the maximum duration of stay.